# Keep Elements of a dictionary rather than pop?

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary

```
l = {'apple': [0, 4], 'orange': [3], 'beer': [9], 'rice': [6], 'melon': [10, 11]}
```

How do I retain only `{apple: [0,4], melon:[10,11]}`

I know the lengths of these are 2.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new `dict` with only what you want using dictionary comprehension:

```
l = {'apple': [0, 4], 'orange': [3], 'beer': [9], 'rice': [6], 'melon': [10, 11]}
result = {key: val for key, val in l.items() if len(val) == 2} # This will only keep entries with length 2.
print(result) # {'apple': [0, 4], 'melon': [10, 11]}
```

Answer (score 0):

filter out items with `if len(value) > 1` of the value of dict.

```
l = {'apple': [0, 4], 'orange': [3], 'beer': [9], 'rice': [6], 'melon': [10, 11]}

result = { key:value for key, value in l.items() if len(value) == 2}

print (result)
```

See the following result:

```
{'apple': [0, 4], 'melon': [10, 11]}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can delete keys where the `len` of the value is not 2.

The only problem is that the dictionary can't change size while you're looping over the keys, so you can get around that by making a copy of the keys first.

```
d = {'apple': [0, 4], 'orange': [3], 'beer': [9], 'rice': [6], 'melon': [10, 11]}
for k in list(d):  # Make copy of keys
    if len(d[k]) < 2:
        del d[k]
print(d)  # -> {'apple': [0, 4], 'melon': [10, 11]}
```

But I would recommend a dictionary comprehension over this.